# I used the word 'social' for an element classname and it chrome won't display it

Tags: html, css, classname

I have a div that I was trying to assign a class name of "social-list" to and it wouldn't show up on the page.

I removed the class name from the div and it appeared. I shortened the name to just "social" and it disappeared. I haven't used that word in my code anywhere else. Using any other name is fine.

I then opened it up in Firefox (was testing with Chrome), and it shows up. No big deal as I can just use a different name, but it's super weird and I'm wondering if anyone else has had this problem?

Comment: Adblocker? Junk-disabling extension? Need a [MCVE]

Comment: That seems as thing any add blocker would do for sure. I had a class name of `cookie-bar` just the other week and got strange behaviour in Chrome that it wouldn't show. I use Chrome as a dev browser only and have a add blocker installed on it to catch behaviour it might cause.